# Ubuntu remote server: automatically clean up temporary files

Tags: server, cleanup

I have the following issue: I am using a remote Ubuntu server to run applications / scripts which generate many temp files. They are deleted only when I reboot the system which is not convenient. I would like to purge the system from temp files automatically everyday to free space on the disk as much as possible, but ONLY those temp files which are not immediately necessary to run the current applications / scripts.

Is there a way to do that?

Ideally I would like to use a shell script with something of the form (I have not tested this code, this is just to show the direction I would like to go):

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo rm -rf /tmp/*
```

But the above code would delete all temp files, including those currently used by the scripts. How can I solve this problem?

NOTE: this question has been asked before in many forms... but not quite in the way that would allow me to solve this (if it has been asked, and I missed it, I apologise).

Comment: Use the find command in a cron job to locate files based on date of creation and pass that to the ```rm``` command to work on!

Comment: Another approach would be to fix your scripts so that they cleaned up after them self en the end of each run.

Comment: Soren A: I would imagine that this would be best practice, indeed. Unfortunately, I am in charge of a server that contains scripts which have been written by other people not necessarily familiar with Ubuntu. There are hundreds of scripts in there, so ensuring that each one of them "cleans up" after itself would be a rather daunting task. But in principle you're right, that could also be a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would use a `find` command and a `cronjob` that runs perhaps once or twice daily as you so desire.

The cronjob for daily execution would be `0 0 * * *` and you could use a find command of say `

```
find /tmp/* -ctime 0 -delete
```

But of course you should adjust the time to remove the files based on the servers needs.

Please see:

- `man find`
- https://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/html_node/find_html/Age-Ranges.html
- Use this to help you setup cronjob: https://crontab.guru

Comment: Please use `-delete` instead of `-exec rm -rf {} \;` to avoid strange effects like (1) deleting the `.` (current) folder or (2) trying to delete a file when its parent folder has already been deleted.

Comment: Thank you George Udosen (and Jos). Your approach seems to be the right one. I appreciate your quick responses.